# What is the rank of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> $A$ is a $15\times15$ matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $(x+1)^5(x-1)^3x^7$ and whose minimal polynomial is $(x+1)^3(x-1)^2x^3$. Then what will be the rank of $A$?

I think the rank of $A$ will be $8$ because rank is the minimum value.

Comment: Looks like zero is an eigenvalue of your matrix.  What can you conclude from that?  What is the nullity of the matrix?  How does the nullity relate to the rank?

Comment: I’m not getting can u elaborate in details?@ demetri

Comment: Zero is a root of the characteristic polynomial.  It has algebraic multiplicity 7.  With that in mind, what can you say about the dimension of the null space?

Comment: Oh sorry dimension of null space will be 7

Comment: Is it correct? @ demetri

Comment: Yes.  Now, what is the rank of the matrix?

Comment: Ranks of A will be 8 by rank nullity theorem but my question is what about minimal polynomials ?

Comment: @Michael Please do not vandalize questions (even your own).

Comment: Do not vandalize your post! That is a rule enforced strictly. You do not "own" the post to that extent (read the fine print). Having said that, you can improve the post by including your own thoughts and adding other context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial tells you about the eigenvalues and their multiplicity,  but nothing that would let you guess the *exact* size of the eigenspaces.

The minimal polynomial now tells you the size of the biggest Jordan block for each eigenvalue, but still not the amount of blocks, which is what you want.

The nullity of $ T $ is the amount of Jordan blocks for the eigenvalue $0 $. The biggest has size $3\times 3 $, and the multiplicity is $7 $, so the extreme configurations are $3-3-1 $ (nullity $3 $) and $3-1-1-1-1 $ (nullity $5 $).

The nullity can be anything between $3 $ and $5 $.

Comment: That's it. You can find actual examples by stacking the relevant Jordan blocks together in a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks alots @ arnaud

Comment: @Michael you're welcome :)